# Google Analytics Management API write requests quota limit

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

What is the Google Analytics Management Write API quota limit? Is it 50 requests per day or 500, because the documentation states that it is 50 requests per day but when I'm filling the quota augmentation demand form, it says that it's 500 requests.

50 requests seem to be too low and it is the case for my project.

On the other hand, where can I check my daily usage of write requests? The console usage tab doesn't show it.

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the Google Form to demand an increase in quota limits

[Google form quota limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uphOk.png)

Google Management Write API is at 500 requests per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quota limits depend a lot upon which methods you are using.  Please consult the [Quota Limits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas) documentation.

> The following quotas apply to Management API, Core Reporting API v3, MCF Reporting API, Metadata API, User Deletion API, and Real Time Reporting API:

- 50,000 requests per project per day, which can be increased.
- 10 queries per second (QPS) per IP address.

  - In the API Console, there is a similar quota referred to as Requests per 100 seconds per user. By default, it is set to 100 requests per 100 seconds per user and can be adjusted to a maximum value of 1,000. But the number of requests to the API is restricted to a maximum of 10 requests per second per user.
- If your application makes all API requests from a single IP address (i.e., on behalf of your users), use the userIP or quotaUser parameter with each request to get full QPS quota for each user. See the standard query parameters summary for details.

> Write APIs
>   These quotas apply to the write (insert, update, patch, and delete) requests:

- 50 write requests per project per day, which can be increased
- 1.5 queries per second (QPS) per Account ID

**actually quota**

response from Google

> the default quota is 50.
>
> There used to be a whitelist so it was effectively 0 until you got whitelisted and then it was 500 (once whitelisted). We removed the whitelist and reduced it to 50 so that people can use the API without having to wait to be whitelsited. If they need more they can request additional quota.

Comment: I read the documentation. The only thing that confuses me is the official quota limit for write requests. Is it 50 or 500? See my edit for a screenshot of the Google Form to demand an increase in quota limits.

Comment: The documentation states Its 50 but can be increased.   If you are seeing it set to 500 in Developer console and you have not set it up.   Then i suspect they have increased the default and not updated the documentation.   If this is true i can contact them and have the documentation corrected.

Comment: The write APIs are nowhere to be found in the Developer Console (I looked into the Analytics API and you can only set queries). So, I can't see what the limit is. However, based on my tests, I'm pretty sure that it's set to 50 requests.

Comment: I sent off an email to google to check.   I will let you know if i hear anything back.    Write methods are only recently out of beta its possible this is an over sight on their part.

Comment: Thank you DaImTo :)

Comment: @DaImTo we also tested and we can reach 500 and then we get response 403.

Comment: they have been tuning the quota limits over the last few months since write operation have come out of beta.  the documentation will probably be updated when they are done.    I will ping them again about it

Answer (score 1):

I wonder exactly the same. I wish to get my write quota increased to 500.
From my experience, the usage of your write requests is under "Queries per day". This morning I only made 50 write requests and it now shows 50/50 000 queries for today. Doesn't really make sense...

Comment: You have to submit a form to request an increase in quotas. [Here is the link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScsIoyWYL4EmLuZi6eHppPVHpRx8hva8ixgk2m5bTTLJ6NQ-A/viewform)

Answer (score 0):

This post won't clear up the write quota but it will show a source of the confusion - hopefully Google will clarify this

This [api-quota-faqs page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/api-quota-faqs#3) clarifies a number of ambiguities regarding quotas and batching (e.g. batching doesn't help with the Management API write quota).

But the 50 vs 500 ambiguity is currently still perpetuated: The current version of that page shows "Last updated April 13, 2018":

> **What is the maximum quota increase limit for Management API write requests?**
>
> The maximum daily quota per project for Management API write requests is **500**. We normally don't grant more than 1,000 to 2,000 write requests per project per day. In some cases, we grant higher limits temporarily. Please include your justification in the quota increase request form.

That page is required reading before submitting [the form to request an increase](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScsIoyWYL4EmLuZi6eHppPVHpRx8hva8ixgk2m5bTTLJ6NQ-A/viewform?fbzx=3050995976380206000) but that shows **50** - see image

[image: the form to request an increase]

Our usage metrics shows 71 successful Management API write requests for the day but we still got write quota errors - so neither 50 nor 500 is validated.

**Regarding finding the usage:**

(I don't see our Management API write quota listed with the other quotas)
The traffic and error metrics are found at APIs & Services > Dashboard.

Clicking on the Analytics API will take you to detailed metrics with listings by method (e.g. insert, update, etc)
URL is:
    https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/metrics?project=project-id-9731708857265513301 (replace with your project id)

Comment: Me too, i don't see anywhere info about currently day usage write request. How i could get this information?